# All Elasticsearch shards are unassigned

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elasticsearch instance and right now it is in red status state. It seems all of my shards are unassigned. This has happened a few times now. Everytime I create a new instance and that fixes the issue for a few weeks. Anybody have any insight? I have also tried to use `_cluster/reroute` but was getting that endpoint wasn't allowed.
Here is response from `_cluster/health`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "aws_cluster_name",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 10,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 4,
  "discovered_master" : true,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 32,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 0.0
}
```

`GET _cat/allocations?v`

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host          ip            node
     0           0b   564.1mb      9.2gb      9.7gb            5 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x -
     0           0b   580.9mb      9.1gb      9.7gb            5 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x -
     0           0b   564.1mb      9.2gb      9.7gb            5 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x -
     0           0b   564.1mb      9.1gb      9.7gb            5 x.x.x.x  x.x.x.x -
    32                                                                                       UNASSIGNED
```

`GET __cat/nodes\?v`

```
ip            heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
x.x.x.x           26          87   1    0.12    0.28     0.29 dir       -      -
x.x.x.x           31          84   2    0.11    0.24     0.25 mr        -      -
x.x.x.x           37          90   4    0.04    0.03     0.03 dir       -      -
x.x.x.x           65          88   4    0.17    0.41     0.35 dir       -      -
x.x.x.x            23          90   2    0.01    0.02     0.02 dir       -      -
x.x.x.x           57          87   2    0.08    0.20     0.24 mr        *      -
x.x.x.x           34          85   2    0.05    0.11     0.16 mr        -      -
x.x.x.x           23          86   5    0.34    0.41     0.30 mr        -      -
x.x.x.x           28          83   1    0.04    0.13     0.16 mr        -      -
x.x.x.x           32          84   2    0.03    0.02     0.00 mr        -      -
```

`GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_yes_decisions=true&include_disk_info=true`

```
{
   "index":"2021.03",
   "shard":3,
   "primary":true,
   "current_state":"unassigned",
   "unassigned_info":{
      "reason":"NODE_LEFT",
      "at":"2021-03-07T07:17:40.171Z",
      "details":"node_left [vyKR44-6U2]",
      "last_allocation_status":"no_valid_shard_copy"
   },
   "can_allocate":"no_valid_shard_copy",
   "allocate_explanation":"cannot allocate because all found copies of the shard are either stale or corrupt",
   "node_allocation_decisions":[
      {
         "node_id":"id",
         "node_name”:"name",
         "node_decision":"no",
         "store":{
            "found":false
         }
      },
      {
         "node_id”:"id",
         "node_name”:"name",
         "node_decision":"no",
         "store":{
            "in_sync":false,
            "allocation_id":"s59AGLR2av"
         }
      },
      {
         "node_id”:"id",
         "node_name”:"name",
         "node_decision":"no",
         "store":{
            "found":false
         }
      },
      {
         "node_id”:"id",
         "node_name”:"name",
         "node_decision":"no",
         "store":{
            "found":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `number_of_nodes: 10 and number_of_data_nodes: 4`. What roles(s) do the 6 other nodes have?

Comment: @Val I believe they are just master-eligible nodes.

Comment: Can you run `GET _cat/nodes?v` + `GET _cat/allocation?v` and share the output please?

Comment: @Val added to original post.

Comment: Thanks, out of curiosity, any reason why you have 6 master-eligible nodes? Waste of $$$

Comment: Can you also add the output you get from `GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_yes_decisions=true&include_disk_info=true` ?

Comment: @Val I don't think it allowed me to do less than that when creating the instance.

Comment: @Val added to original

Comment: 3 master-eligible nodes make sense, 6 don't, pretty sure it's possible on AWS